# Parse String into smaller strings to fit in a fixed width column in java

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I have a textarea that will allow any length of comment, but the we can only store 500 characters in an individual comment. So any comment greater than 500 characters, must be split and inserted as multiple comments. I am looking for help splitting the comment as moving back to lastIndexOf of whitespace, so I dont chop a word in half. Example:

I have a very long comment and i would like it to be split it so it makes sense.

After parse:

Comment 1 : I have a very long comment and i would like it to be split it so it
Comment 2 : makes sense.

Thanks for the help

Comment: are you looking for an algorithm or code ?.you can use substring and lastindexOf methods to the good use and get a solution for your problem

Comment: I can use brute force with substring and lastindexOf and while loops i was wondering if someone could show me how to do it more elegantly.

Comment: You want `List` as result or `String` with end of line `\n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Comment {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String comment = "";
        //This will hold the comments after split
        ArrayList<String> splittedComments = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(comment.length() > 500)
        {
            String splitCOmment = comment.substring(0,500);

            int lastIndexOfWhiteSapce = splitCOmment.lastIndexOf(" ");
            splitCOmment = splitCOmment.substring(0,lastIndexOfWhiteSapce);
            splittedComments.add(splitCOmment);
            //trim off the taken comment and process again
            comment = comment.substring(lastIndexOfWhiteSapce).trim();
        }
        splittedComments.add(comment);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is how i currently have it, thank you for reaffirming my work.

Answer (score 0):

This may (does) work in a global search.

```
 #  "([\\S\\s]{1,500})(?=\\s|$)\\s*"

 ( [\S\s]{1,500} )       # Capture group 1
 (?= \s | $ )
 \s*
```

Just Process capture group 1. The new comment at the split will always
be trimmed of whitespace, making it left justified.

Comment: Java regexes need double escaping

Answer (score 0):

[Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [splitter](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter) can be used for this `Splitter.fixedLength(500)`

### Example code

```
String longComment = "Very long commment to be split ....."; // this is longer :)

List<String> shortComments = new ArrayList<String>();

Splitter splitter = Splitter.fixedLength(500);

for (String shortComment : splitter.split(longComment)) {
    shortComments.add(shortComment);
}
```

### Dependency

```
'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'
```

Comment: this is elegant, but it will split the last word that crosses over characters 499-501